# IMAGEMAGICK - proof sheet, reverse date order (recent first), labeled with date of image

Tags: annotations, imagemagick, montage

I have about 3 dozen images that I'd like to put on a set of proof sheets, in reverse chronological order, labeled (under each image) with the date of the image.

Does anyone know how to do this in imagemagick?

Cheers,
-Bruce

Comment: If they are JPG or TIFF, they likely have an EXIF file, which contains DateTimeOriginal and DateTimeDigitized. So you could extract that and sort the images according to that date.

Comment: Hmm, yes the data is in the exif.  But I'm wondering what the syntax is in imagemagick for sorting in reverse chronological order, and how to label with the file creation date on a proof sheet.  I figure this is doable in IM, but not sure of the commands needed.

Comment: You have to use your OS to do the sort. Linux has a sort method. I would write the image and the data as a line in a file. Then sort the file according to the date. Then read the file and add the corresponding date to the label or comment field in the header (see -comment or -label). The feed all the images as a list or text file to montage, which can add the text under the image. If you want the date in the image rather than under it, you would use -annotate to put the date in the image.